# Adding some customBinding properties to a netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf

I have a tcp config that looks like this.

```
 <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="BindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807" closeTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807" openTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807" receiveTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
```

I need to add some keys that are only avail in the cust. config.

```
 <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustBinding">
          <security>
            <localServiceSettings sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"  sessionKeyRolloverInterval="10675199.02:48:05.4775807" timestampValidityDuration="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Is there a better way of achieving this than translating the tcp config to a custom config(without writing code)?

Answer (score 0):

No, since they do not exist as a property of the already made binding, you need to create a custom one to support the needed properties.